# How to Export Data From MySQL to XML with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, export

I have the following PHP code.  How would I edit this to export to XML?
Please help me, I'm a newbie..

```php
<?php
    $koneksi=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("abdrahmat",$koneksi);
    $id=77;
    $nmtabel="artikel";
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $nmtabel where id_artikel='$id'");
    $r=mysql_fetch_array($sql);// JavaScript Document
```

Comment: Learn PHP XML Parser http://us1.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $array = json_decode(json_encode($r), true);

 $xml      = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
 $importer = $createArrayImporter($xml);
 echo simplexml_pretty_print($importer($array));
```

Comment: Error :
Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml\stack.php on line 13
at $createArrayImporter($xml);